# Is it possible to execute a script with only editing/remove/making files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Just curious,

Would you be able to run a script (let's say `test.sh`) without every doing `./test.sh`? You can only edit/make/remove files. A few things I thought about:

- `crontab`, and then add a line with the current "time + 1 minute" and the script. But crontab doesn't have a file at a location that you can edit, instead you have to edit it with `crontab -e` which is a command, so this one isn't an option.
- `.service file`, make a service that runs the script, but then you'd have to do `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start service` to start the service, so this one also isn't an option.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: This seems like an arbitrary distinction - is `sudo cp myscript /etc/cron.daily` a command, or is it "editing/remove/making" a file? what about `sudo nano /var/spool/cron/crontabs/someuser`?

Comment: See it like I made a samba share of `/`. I can access the complete filesystem from a different device, but can only edit/remove/make files (because it's just a samba share). So `sudo cp myscript /etc/cron.daily` wouldn't be possible, but I CAN put my script there, as I have "samba access" to that folder. P.S. I haven't actually made a samba share of /, relax, it was just a good example.

Comment: You should also explain the reasons behind this question. How is a system supposed to run a command without giving some kind of "trigger" to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is possible if you had write permission for any file that is periodically or incidentally invoked (like your `.profile`). As @steeldriver points out, your user crontab or a timer unit would fit the bill. If you'd like to have it run by any other user on the system (e.g. `root`), you'll need to ask them, as we normally call this an exploit when it happens without consent.